# How to extract React library to separate bundle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, bundles

Is it possible to extract React and(or) ReactDOM libraries to separate bundle via Webpack 4?
For example I have the React app which includes React, ReactDOM and Moment.js packages. So I expect two bundles as the result:

- `react.js` = react + react-dom
- `main.js` = moment + app components

How to split bundles in depends of **name** of the packages but not of frequency of use in entry points?

Comment: The concept you are looking for is usually referred to as "code splitting" and creating a "vendor chunk": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985780/webpack-4-create-vendor-chunk

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I want to know is it possible to implement manual setting of this splitting. So I expect to see in my vendor bundle **only** React and ReactDOM, but not a moment.

Comment: Thanks, @JamesHulse . I checked this thread and it helps me

Comment: This thread won't help in separating only react and react-dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi @VRSY after spending some time in understanding webpack's `SplitChunksPlugins.js` I figured it out how to write RegEx to extract node_modules in spearate vendor chunks.

```
splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](react|react-dom)[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'all',
        }
      }
    }
```

> New chunk would be bigger than 30kb

I was doing a mistake while writing a regex before for module folder name. But relative path regex is a good bet to match the regex.